# Help on understanding the proof for the Ratio Test.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The proof is from the book *Advanced Calculus: An Introduction to Linear Analysis* by *Leonard F. Richardson*.

**(Ratio Test)**: Suppose $x_k>0$ for all $k$ and suppose $$\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} \rightarrow L$$

as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Then we have the following conclusion.

*i.* If $L>1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ diverges.

*Proof:* If $L>1$, then there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq K$ implies $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>1$, which implies $0<x_k<x_{k+1}$, and $x_k \not\rightarrow 0.$ Thus $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ fails to converge because of the $n$th term test. $\blacksquare$

I can't understand how the inequality $0<x_k<x_{k+1}$ was derived. From my understanding, it should be

$$\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>1$$
$$x_{k+1}>x_k>0$$

and since $x_k$ is an increasing sequence, $x_k \not\rightarrow 0$ and $n$th term test follows.

Comment: see here i hope this will help http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/appendices/proof-of-the-ratio-test/proof-of-the-ratio-test/

Comment: It follows from the epsilon-delta definition of a limit.  Basically, we end up with $$\left|\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}-L\right|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you messed up the letters of that proof has, imo, a typo. We can say that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}=L>1\implies \exists\,K\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;k>K\implies \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>\ell$$

where if $\;L-1=\epsilon>0\;$ , then we can take $\;\ell=L-\frac\epsilon2>1\;$, and then

$$x_{k+1}>x_k\ell\implies \lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\neq0\;\;\text{since}\;\;\{x_k\}\;$$

si a positive sequence.